# Why would the proxy on a computer be set to locahost?

Tags: .net, web-services, proxy

Our application sends xml files to a remote computer using a web service. One of our users was unable to send this file, getting an error that the server 127.0.0.1:8881 had refused the connection. Fair enough the proxy setting in IE showed that it should use the mentioned IP address and port.

I could solve the problem by adding to the app.config the following section:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="false"/>
</system.net>
```

Happy as I am that I could help the customer, I don't have the slightest inkling about what was going on.

Why would the proxy be set to localhost? What could I break by advising the user to clear the checkbox?

Comment: If the user is running his own local proxy.

Comment: @SLaks The user is just the average computer user, he has not wittingly configured a proxy, he saw the IE setting for the first time.

Comment: That is probably either security software or a virus.

Comment: @SLaks The user did have a virus when the problem started. So, the IE setting could be a left over after the virus was cleared?

Comment: @SLaks I think you answered the question! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code change can solve your issue but you can also reset Internet Explorer settings and install any cleaner or anti-virus tool as well. 
There are few scenarios which might have set the proxy in the IE as localhost.

- Malware
- Any Add-On installed on IE
- Any utility software installed like fiddler etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You can refer - http://superuser.com/questions/169303/why-are-my-browsers-suddenly-configured-to-use-a-proxy as well.